# Which handler class to import? for webview twice backpress exit app

Tags: android

I want to go back on my app on one time back press.. And if the back key is presesd twice, I want the app to exit. I got the following code on internet and stackoverflow.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
            super.onBackPressed();
            return;
        }

        this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
```

Now I don't know which handler class should be imported here? Either the

```
`java.util.loggin.Handler
```

OR

```
 `android.os.handler
```

Comment: `android.os.handler`. Was it difficult to check the documentation ?

Comment: import `android.os.handler`

Comment: Not easier than posting here. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

The second one (android.os.handler). Can't explain much more. This one is the Handler at operating system level, and the other is used for logging purposes (it's all on the package names, though)

Answer (score 0):

You have to import  android.os.Handler' class . As it provides means to call .post() , .postDelayed(), .sendMessage(), .handleMessage() .

java.util.loggin.Handler will not be useful here in your case.